# Symfony wildcard host route with no named parameter

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony4

I want to host 2 different domains inside a single Symfony 4 application, so I'm using `@Route`'s `host` parameter to declare the domain each page belongs to:

```
/**
 * @Route("/foo", name="foo", host="example.com")
 */
```

This works fine; however, for my local dev server, I will typically use a domain like `example.dev` instead. So the route needs to match multiple extensions. I tried using a named placeholder for this purpose:

```
/**
 * @Route("/foo", name="foo", host="example.{ext}")
 */
```

This works fine for routing, but not for URL generation. For example, if a Twig template attempts to use `{{ path('foo') }}`, I now get the following error:

> Some mandatory parameters are missing ("ext") to generate a URL for route "foo".

**Is there a way to add a wildcard for the host, while still allowing route generation without passing a parameter?**

I know the question sounds odd, as routing must be bi-directional, but **how is this typically handled when one needs to have a dev environment with different domains?**

Is there maybe a way to provide a global, default value for the `ext` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/foo", name="foo", host="example.{ext}", defaults={"ext": "%ext%"})
 */
```

And configure the default value in `config/services.yaml`:

```
parameters:
    ext: 'com'
```

Or better yet, use a constant:

```
parameters:
    ext: '%env(DOMAIN_EXT)%'
```

And define it in your `.env` and/or `.env.local` as needed:

```
DOMAIN_EXT=com
```

---

### Alternative

It may be even better to allow the whole host to be configurable. In this case, it looks like:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/foo", name="foo", host="%domain.name%")
 */
```

And as above, configure the domain name in `config/services.yaml`, with or without a constant:

```
parameters:
    domain.name: '%env(DOMAIN_NAME)%'
```

Comment: The alternative way worked for me in Symfony 5.1